# Jenkins can not load after upgrade to version 2.150

Tags: java, jenkins, ubuntu-16.04, hudson, devops

I use apt-get upgrade and it upgrade my Jenkins to 2.150 then I can not access to the Jenkins UI. 
This is Jenkins Logs:

```
Jan 17, 2019 2:30:16 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Jan 17, 2019 2:30:16 PM jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackNotifier$Migrator onLoaded
INFO: Starting Settings Migration Process
Jan 17, 2019 2:30:16 PM jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackNotifier$Migrator onLoaded
INFO: Completed Settings Migration Process
Jan 17, 2019 2:30:16 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
Jan 17, 2019 2:30:25 PM hudson.model.AsyncAperiodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Update IdP Metadata from URL PeriodicWork
Jan 17, 2019 2:30:25 PM hudson.model.AsyncAperiodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Update IdP Metadata from URL PeriodicWork. 2 ms
Jan 17, 2019 2:30:27 PM com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.gerrit.trigger.GerritProjectListUpdater tryLoadProjectList
INFO: Not connected to localhost, waiting for 32 second(s)
Jan 17, 2019 2:30:59 PM com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.gerrit.trigger.GerritProjectListUpdater tryLoadProjectList
INFO: Not connected to localhost, waiting for 64 second(s)
Jan 17, 2019 2:32:03 PM com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.gerrit.trigger.GerritProjectListUpdater tryLoadProjectList
INFO: Not connected to localhost, waiting for 64 second(s)
```

This is service status

```
● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2019-01-17 14:29:45 +07; 7min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 23202 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/jenkins stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 23279 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0

Jan 17 14:29:43 mep-lab-jenkins systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Jan 17 14:29:43 mep-lab-jenkins jenkins[23279]: Correct java version found
Jan 17 14:29:44 mep-lab-jenkins jenkins[23279]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
Jan 17 14:29:44 mep-lab-jenkins su[23334]: Successful su for jenkins by root
Jan 17 14:29:44 mep-lab-jenkins su[23334]: + ??? root:jenkins
Jan 17 14:29:44 mep-lab-jenkins su[23334]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Jan 17 14:29:45 mep-lab-jenkins jenkins[23279]:    ...done.
Jan 17 14:29:45 mep-lab-jenkins systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
```

Please help me. The webpage spinning forever

Comment: How is the Jenkins process? Does it exist? Is it zombie or fully gone, or appears to be healthy? (`ps -ef | grep -i jenkins`)

Comment: [SOLVED] The problems because the CAS Plugin in Jenkins, it lead to an infinity loop after authenticate with the CAS Server. Developers are in theirs way to fix the problems. https://github.com/fcrespel/jenkins-cas-plugin/issues/9